# Prometheus query promql to make average on the same field

Tags: prometheus, promql

On my prometheus database, I have got metrics from three different host, I want to make the average between them, like that I can make aggreagation :

```
information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom01"}
information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom02"}
information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom03"}
```

I try to sum those three metrics and sub by three on the only query command, like that :

```
(information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom01"} +
information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom02"} +
information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom03"})/3
```

but it does not work<

Moreover, I try the sum + rate, does not work also

```
sum by (host) (rate(information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99"})[5m])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
(scalar(information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom01"}) +
 scalar(information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom02"}) +
 scalar(information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host="prom03"})
) / 3
```

but it's easier if you do:

```
(sum(information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host=~"prom0(1|2|3)"}))
) / 3
```

Or simply:

```
avg(information{application=~"$app",access=~"$access",quantile="0.99", host=~"prom0(1|2|3)"})
```